# How to retrieve href from rss in php

Tags: php, rss

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<category term="Search"/>
<category term="Design"/>
<title>Ijazilla</title>
<link rel='next' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.ijazialla.blogspot.com'/>
?>
```

my php code is:

```
  <?php xml=simplexml_load_file("xmlfile.xml");
    foreach($xml->children() as $child){

       echo $child->title;
       echo $child->category[term];
       echo $child->link[href];

    } ?>
```

how to retrieve "link href" and two "category term"?